# Access local function inside ko.computed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

How come this line of code doesnt work.

Im using durandal/knockout and i have a structure like this

```
define(function () {

    var vm = function() {

    compute: ko.computed(function() {
         return _compute(1); // fail
    });

    var _compute= function(e) {
        return e;
    }    
 }

 return vm;
});
```

Basically I am just trying to access the private method _compute - but KO.compute doesnt allow that?

Even if i make it public, I still cant access it.
I trying to implement [revealing pattern](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) in this, but still no luck!

```
 var vm = function() {

    compute: ko.computed(function() {
         return this._compute(1); // still failing 
    });

    this._compute= function(e) {
        return e;
    }    
 }
```

update: so far, only this one works

```
define(function () {

   var vm = function() {

   var self = this;

   var self._compute= function(e) {
        return e;
    } 

    compute: ko.computed(function() {
         return this._compute(1); // works
    }, self);

 }
```

but like I said, _compute is not meant to be exposed.

Update: actually its another error.

this one now works

define(function () {

```
   var vm = function() {

   var self = this;

   var _compute= function(e) {
        return e;
    } 

    compute: ko.computed(function() {
         return _compute(1); // works
    });

 }
```

Basically, just need to declare the private function before the ko.computed prop!

Thanks!

**Additional Note:**

Why does it need to be declared before the computed function? I prefer all my "properties" in the first lines while the functions in the bottom. It is neater i Think.

Comment: could you please provide jsfiddle demo?

Comment: `compute: ko.computed(function() {` you are defining a label LOL

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/CLTBN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax does not create a property when in a function:

```
compute: ko.computed(function() {
     return _compute(1); // fail
});
```

You have to use `=` instead of `:`.

Try this

```
 var vm = function() {
    var self = this;
    var _compute = function(e) {
        return e;
    }
    this.compute = ko.computed(function() {
         return _compute(1);
    });    
 }
```

Also note that this is not how you should use a `computed` observable. *It should contain calls to other observables*!
From [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

> What if you’ve got an observable for firstName, and another for
>   lastName, and you want to display the full name? That’s where computed
>   observables come in - **these are functions that are dependent on one or
>   more other observables, and will automatically update whenever any of
>   these dependencies change**.

Comment: ideally i want the _compute to be private also!

Comment: seems like you have to put _compute before the this.compute!

Comment: The syntax is valid. Javascript has labels :)

Comment: There's no reason to expose `_compute` to the world. Just define a `function _compute() {}` inside the constructor function and it will only be available to the computed function.

Comment: yeah! actually its another error but fixed it already, your solution works now! thanks!

Comment: But why does it need to be declared before? I prefer all my "properties" in the first lines while the functions in the bottom. It is neater i Think.

Comment: When you use `ko.computed`, you are actually calling a function, and it starts with evaluating the parameter you give. So basically you call the `_compute` function before declaring it